# Add knockout binding dynamically to existing element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm creating a `bindingHandler` that will implicitly or programatically add bindings to an element. How can I achieve this without losing other elements binding? I use `applyBindingAccessorsToNode`.

```
ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, {
    optionsAfterRender: function (option, item) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, { attr: { "data-key": item[config.observableKey] } }, item);
        }
    }
}, bindingContext);
```

Comment: Have you tried something already? Can you give an outset of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I tried using applyBindingAccessorsToNode but I can't find any documentation on where to use it, I get this idea on this [github issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2126).

Comment: Please add more details to your question so we can give a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask the similar question on [knockout repository](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2130) and **@Michael Best** answered that I can achieve it through [preprocessor](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html#binding-preprocessor-reference) `addBinding` parameter.